# How to get access to photos using ALAssetsLibrary without request location access in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I requested photo access using ALAssetsLibrary in iOS5. It asks user app can access location service or not. If user choose no, my app cannot access to photo.

How to access to photo with out asking user for access to location service?

Special thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fall back to using the UIImagePickerController if the user denies you location access. It's pretty bad, I know.

Comment: But this app can pick multiple image without asking location access  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mei-tu-xiu-xiu/id416048305?l=en&mt=8 how does it do?

Comment: Yeah, I think these guys are being clever and using a UIImagePickerController but shifting it up vertically and not dismissing it after a photo is picked. As you pick photos they array them at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You are right, they really do it this way. But they can't do too much interaction on UIImagePickerController, such as add a mark image to photo. Thanks for help!